# Why is Socket's Available > 0 just after being returned from AcceptAsync()?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm encountering this weird issue whilst working with .NET High-Performance Sockets.
Just after I get a new Socket via an AcceptAsync() op, **the [Available] property is equal to some non-zero value**, usually 64. At a closer look, I can see that all the available bytes' values in the Socket's buffer are set to 0.

Client-side, the only operation ran is ConnectAsync(). No SendAsync(), no nothing.

That holds regarding of Nagle's enabled state.

Anyone ever encountered this issue?

P.S.: I will update & post some code if needed, but it's kind of a big snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this myself.

The SocketAsyncEventArgs instances used by the clients to connect to the server had their [Count] property (the number of bytes set in the SAEA's shared buffer) larger than 0. In effect, the ConnectAsync() operation initiated by the clients would trigger the AcceptAsync()'s I/O callback to be called on the server along with a [BytesTransfered] value equal to the stated [Count]'s one (practically "connecting and sending the set buffer in one go"].